# How to identify reachability of a certain commit?

Tags: git

I am trying to clean a repo:

```
local FIRST_COMMIT="bf450342272a94117d78eae34a140a2a39359dad"
git branch -d bad-master
git remote remove bad-remote
git rev-parse ${FIRST_COMMIT} > .git/shallow
git fsck --unreachable
git gc --prune=now
```

The idea is the following:

- keep a single branch (the `develop`) branch
- remove all unwanted references
- cut the history in the `develop` branch, with `.git/shallow` / `gc --prune`

After doing this, I have verified the following:

- there are no remotes defined
- there are no tags defined
- there is a single branch: `develop`
- the history in the `develop` branch is indeed reduced up to the specified commit

But there is still a problem:

```
git rev-list --all
```

Lists commits which are not reachable through the `develop` branch!

I do not understand why `git fsck --unreachable` does not list that, and why `git gc --prune=now` does not remove those commits. The only explanation is that those commits *are reachable*, through *other* references. Which ones?

How can I identify how a given commit is reachable?

What I expect is:

- identify a reference which I was missing up to now (branch / remote / tag / ???)
- remove that reference
- after that, `prune` will remove the unwanted commits.

Answer (score 2):

Use `git for-each-ref` to iterate through all references (the default is to display them and their hash IDs and object types).

Note that `git for-each-ref` only looks at refs, not at their corresponding reflogs.  Use `git reflog` on each ref to examine (or expire) their reflogs.  Deleting a ref deletes its reflog, so if there are no other refs, the problem is most likely the reflog for `develop`; however, `git rev-list --all` looks at all refs but not reflogs, so I expect there is some other ref finding these commits.